Match manufacturer and buyer ZIP code and display Woocommerce special shipping option
I added to WooCommerce products a custom field to define the manufacturer zip code. This works fine.
Now, I want if the zip code of the product/manufacturer matches the zip code of the customer, to show a special shipping price.
This is my code:
// Add a field to enter the manufacturer's ZIP code on the product page
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'dodaj_zip_proizvodjaca');
function dodaj_zip_proizvodjaca() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(array(
        'id' => '_zip_proizvodjaca',
        'label' => 'ZIP proizvođača',
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'description' => 'Unesite ZIP kod proizvođača ovog proizvoda.',
    ));
}

// Save the manufacturer ZIP code value
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'sacuvaj_zip_proizvodjaca');
function sacuvaj_zip_proizvodjaca($post_id) {
    $zip = isset($_POST['_zip_proizvodjaca']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['_zip_proizvodjaca']) : '';
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_zip_proizvodjaca', $zip);
}


// Add a separate shipping method if the ZIP codes are the same
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'poseban_nacin_dostave_za_isti_zip', 10, 2);
function poseban_nacin_dostave_za_isti_zip($rates, $package) {
    $isti_zip = false;
    $zip_kupca = WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode();

    foreach ($package['contents'] as $item_id => $values) {
        $product_id = $values['product_id'];
        $zip_proizvodjaca = get_post_meta($product_id, '_zip_proizvodjaca', true);

        if ($zip_proizvodjaca && $zip_kupca && $zip_proizvodjaca == $zip_kupca) {
            $isti_zip = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($isti_zip) {
        // Add a special shipping method
        $rates['poseban_nacin_dostave'] = array(
            'id' => 'poseban_nacin_dostave',
            'label' => 'Specijalna dostava za isti ZIP',
            'cost' => 180, // besplatna dostava ili cena po izboru
            'taxes' => '',
            'calc_tax' => 'per_order',
        );
    }

    return $rates;
}

But I am not able to make it work. What should I need to change in my code?

Your code doesn't work, as you need first to set up (define) a Flat Rate shipping method in WooCommerce settings, with the correct cost and settings.
So if the manufacturer postcode doesn't match with the customer postcode, you will hide this Flat Rate shipping method, but if it matches you will display it (hiding optionally other shipping methods).
Once done, you need to change your last function with:
// Add a separate shipping method if the ZIP codes are the same
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'poseban_nacin_dostave_za_isti_zip', 10, 2);
function poseban_nacin_dostave_za_isti_zip($rates, $package) {
    // Here below define the targeted shipping method rate ID
    $targeted_method = 'flat_rate:11'; 

    $zip_kupca = WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode();
    $isti_zip = false;

    // Loop through cart items for the current shipping package
    foreach ($package['contents'] as $item) {
        $zip_proizvodjaca = get_post_meta($item['product_id'], '_zip_proizvodjaca', true);

        if ($zip_proizvodjaca && $zip_kupca && $zip_proizvodjaca == $zip_kupca) {
            $isti_zip = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If postcodes doesn't match
    if ( ! $isti_zip && isset($rates[$targeted_method]) ) {
        // Hide the targeted shipping method
        unset($rates[$targeted_method]);
    } 
    // If postcodes matches (optional)
    else {
        // Hide other shipping methods
        return array($targeted_method => $rates[$targeted_method]);
    }
    return $rates;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.
Important: Empty your cart to refresh the shipping methods cached data.

How to get the correct shipping rate ID?
The following function will display, near the footer, the available shipping rates IDs:
add_action('wp_footer', 'display_shipping_methods_rate_ids');
function display_shipping_methods_rate_ids() {
    echo '<pre><h4>Available Shipping Methods Rates</h4>
    <table><thead><tr><th>Shipping method</th><th>Rate ID</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $package_key => $package ){
        $data = WC()->session->get( "shipping_for_package_{$package_key}" );
        foreach ( $data['rates'] as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$rate->label.'</td><td>'.$rate_id.'</td></tr>';
        }
    }
    echo '</tbody></table></pre>';
}

Once you get the correct shipping rate ID to be used in the previous code, you can remove this code snippet.
